# Sort CSV File by Timestamp with Python

Tags: python, csv, sorting, timestamp

I'm trying to sort the content of a csv file by the given timestamps but it just doesn't seem to work for me. They are given in such a way:

```
2021-04-16T12:59:26+02:00
```

So year-month-day-T-hour-minute-second-timezone.

I have already tried:

```
data = csv.reader(open('List_32_Data.csv','r'))
data = sorted(data, key = lambda row: datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%HHMM"))
```

But i just get the error:

```
sre_constants.error: redefinition of group name 'H' as group 7; was group 4 at position 157
```

Could someone help please?

Comment: It appears you cannot use `%H` twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can read in your error and a quick search I found your pattern `"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%HHMM"` have a problem.

From [Python string to datetime - JournalDev](https://www.journaldev.com/23365/python-string-to-datetime-strptime) I can read that there is **Directive** `%z` with **Description**

> UTC offset in the form ±HHMM[SS] (empty string if the object is naive).

and **example output**

> (empty), +0000, -0400, +1030

Therefor I'd say your pattern should be:

```
"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%z"
```

Regarding your error it tells a lot. You defined the `%H` both at your 4th and 7th group which is the case in yout pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, you have helped me alot already! I have changed the Format to `2021-04-16 12:59:26+02:00´ since i thought the "T" might cause problems but now he still says that  "time data '2021-04-16 12:59:26+02:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'". Could you please explain why? I thought I sticked very strictly to the given format directives

Comment: Hmm, I don't have Python on this computer so went to an online compiler. From there your format should work.

both:

datetime.strptime("2021-04-16 12:59:26+02:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")

and:

datetime.strptime("2021-04-16T12:59:26+02:00","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")

do compile at https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

with "from datetime import datetime"